# java: List of String Arrays and remove

Tags: java, list, junit

In a test like this:

```
    @Test
    public void test() {
        List<String[]> l = new LinkedList<String[]>();
        l.add(new String [] {"test", "123"});
        l.add(new String [] {"test", "456"});
        l.add(new String [] {"test", "789"});

        assertEquals(3, l.size());

        l.remove(new String [] {"test", "456"});

        assertEquals(2, l.size());
    }
```

the second assertion(=2) fails as the `equals/hashcode` used in `list.remove` are the `default` for Object.
Is there a way to make the list able to use `Arrays.equals/Arrays.hashcode` to compare the arrays? Or the only solution is wrapping the String arrays in an object and overriding `equals/hashcode`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Guava, there is. You will need to implement an [`Equivalence<String[]>`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html):

```
public final class MyEquivalence
    extends Equivalence<String[]>
{
    @Override
    protected boolean doEquivalent(final String[] a, final String[] b)
    {
        return Arrays.equals(a, b);
    }

    @Override
    protected int doHash(final String[] t)
    {
        return Arrays.hashCode(t);
    }
}
```

You would then need to have your list being a `List<Equivalence.Wrapper<String[]>>`, and insert/remove/etc using your `Equivalence`'s `.wrap()` method:

```
final Equivalence<String[]> eq = new MyEquivalence();
list.add(eq.wrap(oneValue));
list.remove(eq.wrap(anotherValue));
```

Use Guava. Repeat after me. Use Guava :p

Comment: Ok! I will USE GUAVA! GUAVA! GUAVAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA! thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

You are creating a new Object reference and passing it to the `remove()` method . From the data you posted , it looks like you can create a custom class with two properties and override its `equals()` and `hashCode()` instead of storing them as `String[]` OR Keep the reference to the `String[]` object inserted and use that reference to remove.

Answer (score 2):

The `List` method are often based on the `Object` method `equals(Object o)` which compare the object's reference by default.
You may store the tab if you want remove it later, or create your own class and override `equals(Object o)` ;)

```
    @Test
    public void test() {
        List<String[]> l = new LinkedList<String[]>();
        l.add(new String [] {"test", "123"});
        String[] tab = new String [] {"test", "456"};
        l.add(tab);
        l.add(new String [] {"test", "789"});

        assertEquals(3, l.size());

        l.remove(tab);

        assertEquals(2, l.size());
    }
```

Comment: No, in my case I have exactly a new Array String with same values. So the "default" Object.equals/hashcode won't work

Comment: Yes, it was what I wrote in my question and I would like avoid that if possible

Answer (score 0):

By the way, Java 8 introduces a new [removeIf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) method that *removes all of the elements of this collection that satisfy the given predicate*

It can be used to easily remove an array of strings from the list:

```
List<String[]> l = new LinkedList<String[]>();
l.add(new String [] {"test", "123"});
l.add(new String [] {"test", "456"});
l.add(new String [] {"test", "789"});

String[] newArray = new String[] {"test", "456"};
l.removeIf(array -> Arrays.equals(array, newArray));
```